# how to send file formats other than txt using tcp

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am trying to send pdf files over to clients using tcp connections. Somehow, the file is corrupted. I wonder if tcp support non-txt files?
    this is a simple server program

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


class server{
public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception 
{
  Socket s = null;
  int firsttime=1;
  while(true) {
  ServerSocket s_sock = new ServerSocket(3248);
  Socket socket = s_sock.accept();
  BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
  DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
  File myFile = new File ("/Users/wchen48/Desktop/123.pdf");
  byte [] mybyte = new byte[(int)myFile.length()];
  OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
  System.out.println("sending......" + mybyte.length + "Byte");

  os.write(mybyte,0,mybyte.length);
  os.flush();
  socket.close();
  s_sock.close();

   }

} //end of main
```

This is the client:

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class client{
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
  Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 3248);
  byte[] mybytearray = new byte[11536];
  InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
  FileOutputStream fos = new     
  FileOutputStream("/Users/wchen48/Documents/123.pdf");
  bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
  int bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
  bos.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
  bos.close();
  sock.close();
}
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Bytes are transferred, if all the bytes are sent and received properly, then the file should never be corrupted.

Comment: What are `bf` and `dos` for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Zielu and Juned said, plus:

You need loops at both server and client.

At the server, choose a reasonable-size buffer and loop around.  Try to read [buffer length] bytes into it from the file.  Then USE THE RETURNED VALUE FROM THE READ CALL to both check for errors, (result<0), or end-of-file, (result 0), or use the value in the network write call as the number of bytes to write. DO NOT use the buffer length - it may not be full.  When you get 0, close the file and socket, else loop back and read some more.

At the client, choose a reasonable-size buffer and loop around.  Try to read [buffer length] bytes into it from the socket. Then USE THE RETURNED VALUE FROM THE READ CALL to both check for errors, (result<0), or socket close, (result 0), or use the value in the file write call as the number of bytes to write.  DO NOT use the buffer length - it may not be full.  When you get 0, exit the loop and close the file, else loop back and read some more.

Comment: thanks. I was trying to send the whole file at once to see if it was working. But, adding a loop would work. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you dont read content of your file into the buffer mybyte you later send through socket, so you send 00000....

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for getting the corrupted file is the fixed number of bytes(11536) that you are trying to read. You should try to read all the bytes received on the socket rather than fixed number of bytes.

Comment: Yeah, needs a loop at both server and client.